# Arrival and departure dates, datepicker with 2 months

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I have 2 jquery datepickers, first for arrival date where min date is today and second for departure where min date is arrival date +1 day. Datepickers show 2 months.

The problem is, when arrival datepicker shows **July** and **August** and i select for example **25 August**, it set min date of departure datepicker to 26 August and change months to **August** and **September**. I want it to stay on **July** and **August** like arrival datepicker.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle/can you put one together?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a datepicker with default values, it only shows the current month. In your case, you show 2 consecutive months, which simply means, datepicker will show current and next month, **unless** you interfere with its settings via setDate.

So, you gotto set the date for the arrival datepicker somewhere. If you don't want the second datepicker to show another month but stick to the very same months, just like departure one, simply do not set the date for it.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tv4ygbv6/1/) where you can play with the idea. In order to mimic your case, I put together two datepickers: departure and arrival. When user selects a date from departure, arrival datepickers are aligned. In the code, you will see a line of comment right above the line which I set the date for the arrival datePicker. If you comment out that line, you will notice that arrival date will not change. You must have something similar in your code.

```
// Comment out following line to stop return datepicker from changing    
$("#arrival").datepicker("setDate","+" + diffDays +"d");
```

I hope it helps.

**__UPDATE__**

Actually above should help (sorta!). Here is the idea (but I really don't think this is the desired functionality by datepicker). Right now, return datepicker is set to at least next day of departure day. This way, it is guaranteed that  your return date can not be set to anything prior to your departure. (This is what I suggested above to find the line where you set the date to return datepicker and comment it out). Instead of that, what you can do is to set the return datepicker to 30 days before the departure. That way, it will be guaranteed to have the same months (however user **CAN** select a return date prior to departure date and you have to take care of it in your business logic and I really think it is a bad idea).

[Here is the new fiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/tv4ygbv6/5/)

```
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) - 30;

// Comment out following line to stop return datepicker from changing    
$("#arrival").datepicker("setDate","+" + diffDays +"d");
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not. I also set minDate [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/tv4ygbv6/3/), and it still changing.

Comment: @Becon take a look at my update above. Although there is a solution, I think that it is a bad idea to go with that route.